# poisson distribution to get pdf

Tags: probability

The probability density function of the waiting time for a given process is 
$$f(t) = \lambda e^{-\lambda t}; t >0$$
The cumulative: 
$$F(t) = 1 - e^{-\lambda t}$$

You are waiting for an email, and have already waited time $t_0$. What is the probability density function of the additional waiting time until the next email arrives?

Comment: Hello, welcome to mathSE!! Please tell us what have you tried

Comment: I'm not sure how to start

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** The exponential distribution is **memoryless**. So the distribution of the additional time is the same as the distribution of the waiting time.

**Remark:** We give a proof of the memorylessness property. Let $W$ be the total waiting time. Let $A$ be the event that $W\ge t+t_0$, and $B$ be the event $W\gt t_0)$. Then
$$\Pr(W\gt t+t_0|W\gt t_0)=\frac{\Pr((W\gt t+t_0) \cap (W\gt t_0))}{\Pr(W\gt t_0)}.$$
But $\Pr((W\gt t+t_0) \cap (W\gt t_0))=\Pr(W\gt t+t_0)=e^{-\lambda(t+t_0)}$ and $\Pr(W\gt t_0)=e^{-\lambda t_0}$.

Divide. We get
$$\Pr(W\gt t+t_0|W\gt t_0)=e^{-\lambda t}.$$
This proves that the conditional distribution of the additional waiting time has the same distribution as the ordinary waiting time.

Answer (score 1):

$$
\Pr(T-t_0\leq t \mid T>t_0)=\frac{\Pr(T-t_0\leq t, T>t_0)}{\Pr(T>t_0)}=\frac{e^{-Rt_0}-e^{-R(t+t_0)}}{e^{-Rt_0}}=1-e^{-Rt}.
$$
As mentioned in the other answer, this is **the memoryless property** of exponential random variables.